# String or binary data would be truncated on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an error while executing my project. I have two commands in this button. Can someone help me with this? I can't detect the problem. It is working fine before but now it occurred a problem. I'm developing an library system

```
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Borrowbook ([Student ID], ISBN, Title, Date, [Due Date]) VALUES (@StudentID, @ISBN, @Title, @Date, @DueDate)";
Control[] controls = { textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };

foreach (Control c in controls)
{
   if (c.Text.Trim() == "")
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please complete the fields", "Information...",
                      MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning,
                      MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
      return;
   }
}

SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@StudentID", SqlDbType.NChar);
p1.Value = textBox2.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@ISBN", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
p2.Value = textBox4.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

SqlParameter p3 = new SqlParameter("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar);
p3.Value = textBox3.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p3);

SqlParameter p4 = new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
p4.Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p4);

SqlParameter p5 = new SqlParameter("@DueDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
p5.Value = duedate.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(p5);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE Books SET Availability = 'Borrowed' WHERE ISBN = '" + textBox4.Text + "'");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO Penalty([Student ID], Title, [Date Borrow], [Due Date]) VALUES  (@StudentID1, @Title1, @Date1, @Date2)");

SqlParameter pp1 = new SqlParameter("@StudentID1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
pp1.Value=textBox2.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pp1);

SqlParameter pp3 = new SqlParameter("@Title1", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
pp3.Value = textBox3.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pp3);

SqlParameter pp4 = new SqlParameter("@Date1", SqlDbType.DateTime);
pp4.Value = dateTimePicker1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pp4);

SqlParameter pp5 = new SqlParameter("@Date2",SqlDbType.DateTime);
pp5.Value=duedate.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pp5);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("The books has been successfully borrowed!", "Information ... ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

Comment: The error is on the last cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Its working now, the other table is too short thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: where exactly does this error happen? You have multiple commands in your code - which one causes the error?

Secondly: the error is clear: at least one of your values that you're trying to store is too long. So you might have a `Varchar(20)` defined in your database, and you're trying to store a string of 25 characters length.

Find this problem, fix it. Either make the database column longer (e.g. increase its length to 25 characters), or shorten the string that you're inserting into that column to respect the defined maximum length.

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't really help you find out *which* parameter is the problem - you'll have to do your own debugging & see which ones is too long.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("The books has been successfully borrowed!", "Information ... ",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

Just as a matter of interest, how do you know 'The books has been successfully borrowed' - you aren't handling any error that might be generated when you execute the command.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If the command fails, `ExecuteNonQuery()` throws an exception, so it doesn't get to the `MessageBox.Show` call.